# What is the flattening process in AUTOSAR

Tags: system, autosar

What is the flattening process actually means in AUTOSAR Methodology workflow?

I know that is a process that the ECU Extract made from the System Description but I want to know the detail steps of this process.

Comment: Are you aware of the hierarchical concept of (potentially nested) compositions?

Comment: Yes, I know about Top level composition and differences between SWcomposition and how the designed software (VFB level) should be referenced in the system description as a RootComposition but I am confused about the detail steps of flattening process.

Comment: OK. Seems that you are indeed more knowledgable than me. Which is good. I cannot contribute. But you might improve the focus of your question, if you write as much as possible about what you *do* understand about the flattening. Maybe highlight certain steps in between which you particularily want details on. (And by the way, I will appreciate seeing answers....)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might take a look in the AUTOSAR_TR_Methodology.pdf of the respective AUTOSAR revision, e.g. R21-11:

- Chapter 3.3.2.14 System Flat Map
- Chapter 3.3.4.2.9 ECU Flat Map
- Chapter 3.3.4.1.3 Flatten Software Compositions

In short, it converts the possible deep hierarchies of SwCompositions and their contained SwComponentPrototypes (instances of SwComponents) into a single/flat representation of all the SwComponent instances in a single SwComposition.  There might be some activities to regenerate the DataTypeMappings for the SwComponent instances and also to resolve name conflicts due to multiple instances of the same component.

Answer (score 1):

The system description contains information of all ECUs. If you want to take the contents of only one ECU and also the other related info like Signals , Sw composition , ports , data mapping , compu method etc etc. This process of extracting the contents of one ecu is called flattening.